# No instance for (MonadResource IO) arising from a use of ‘writeBlob’

Tags: git, haskell, gitlib

I am trying to create a commit using [gitlib](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitlib-3.1.3), but it does not quite work as expected. What I'm stuck at is the application of function [writeBlob](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitlib-3.1.3/docs/Git-Blob.html#v:writeBlob). Here is my source code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}

module GitOperation where

import Git
import Git.Libgit2 (lgFactory, LgRepo(..) )
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Time.LocalTime
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Control.Monad.State
import Conduit

repositoryOptions :: RepositoryOptions
repositoryOptions = RepositoryOptions { repoPath = "data" , repoWorkingDir = Just "data", repoIsBare = False , repoAutoCreate = True}
  
main :: IO ()
main = do
  repo <- openRepository lgFactory repositoryOptions
  runReaderT (addFileToRepository "content4.txt" "content4" "added content4 file") repo

addFileToRepository :: TreeFilePath -> String -> CommitMessage -> ReaderT LgRepo IO ()
addFileToRepository path content commitMessage = do
  now <- lift getCurrentTime
  timezone <- lift getCurrentTimeZone
  treeBuilder <- newTreeBuilder Nothing
  repo <- ask
  blobOid <- createBlobUtf8 $ T.pack content
  writeBlob (BS.unpack path) (BlobString $ BS.pack content)
  transf <- lift $ runReaderT (runStateT (runTreeT currentTreeOid) treeBuilder) repo 
  let (year, month, day) = toGregorian $ utctDay now
      timeOfDay = localTimeOfDay $ utcToLocalTime timezone now
      s = Signature {
         signatureName = "username", 
         signatureEmail = "me@website.com", 
         signatureWhen = ZonedTime { 
            zonedTimeToLocalTime = LocalTime {
                localDay = fromGregorian year month day,
                localTimeOfDay = timeOfDay                                                       
            },
            zonedTimeZone = TimeZone {
                timeZoneMinutes = 180,
                timeZoneSummerOnly = False,
                timeZoneName = "EEST"
            }
         }
      }  in do
  lift $ print s
  ci <- case transf of 
    (oid, builder) -> do 
      newOid <- createTree $ putEntry path BlobEntry {blobEntryKind = PlainBlob, blobEntryOid = blobOid}
      createCommit [] newOid s s commitMessage Nothing
  lift $ print $ commitLog ci
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
Main.hs:125:3: error:
    • No instance for (MonadResource IO)
        arising from a use of ‘writeBlob’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        writeBlob (unpack path) (BlobString $ pack content)
      In the expression:
        do now <- lift getCurrentTime
           timezone <- lift getCurrentTimeZone
           treeBuilder <- newTreeBuilder Nothing
           repo <- ask
           ....
      In an equation for ‘addFileToRepository’:
          addFileToRepository path content commitMessage
            = do now <- lift getCurrentTime
                 timezone <- lift getCurrentTimeZone
                 treeBuilder <- newTreeBuilder Nothing
                 ....
    |
125 |   writeBlob (BS.unpack path) (BlobString $ BS.pack content)
    |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I cannot quite understand how to make `writeBlob` the instance of `MonadResource IO`. Documentation for `gitlib` is quite obscure.

Without `writeBlob` file gets stuck with `delete` mark in staging area and nothing is really get committed even though `git log` says it is there:

```
Projects/test/data on  master [?] 
❯ git status
 D content4.txt

Projects/test/data on  master [?] 
❯ git log
commit 90b3f8ac01ae590e5e7726046a59a5d9944ab88c (HEAD -> master)
Author: username <me@website.com>
Date:   Mon May 17 15:26:38 2021 +0300

    added content4 file
```

If somebody could help with resolving this issue and hopefully make commit created as expected, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to irc.freenode.net#haskell and user dminuoso, solution is finally found.

```
addFileToRepository :: TreeFilePath -> String -> CommitMessage -> ReaderT LgRepo IO ()
addFileToRepository path content commitMessage = do
  now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
  timezone <- liftIO getCurrentTimeZone
  treeBuilder <- newTreeBuilder Nothing
  repo <- ask
  blobOid <- createBlobUtf8 $ T.pack content
  transf <- lift $ runReaderT (runStateT (runTreeT currentTreeOid) treeBuilder) repo 
  let (year, month, day) = toGregorian $ utctDay now
      timeOfDay = localTimeOfDay $ utcToLocalTime timezone now
      in do
  liftIO $ print $ s year month day timeOfDay
  case transf of 
    (oid, _) -> do 
      oid <- mutateTreeOid oid $ putBlob path blobOid
      reference <- resolveReference $ T.pack "HEAD"
      case reference of 
        Nothing -> do
          ci <- createCommit [] oid (s year month day timeOfDay) (s year month day timeOfDay) commitMessage (Just "refs/heads/master") 
          liftIO $ print $ commitLog ci
        Just reference -> do
          obj <- lookupObject reference
          case obj of 
             CommitObj headCommit -> do
              ci <- createCommit [commitOid headCommit] oid (s year month day timeOfDay) (s year month day timeOfDay) commitMessage (Just "refs/heads/master") 
              liftIO $ print $ commitLog ci
```

I didn't need writeBlob after all, just needed to learn how to properly `createCommit`. This was possible thanks to [smoke tests for gitlib](https://github.com/jwiegley/gitlib/blob/master/gitlib-test/Git/Smoke.hs) found on github.

As @torek reasonably pointed out, gitlib does not work with working tree, only with repository contents. Therefore files in `git status` appear to be missing in staging even though they are apparently present in the repository submitted by relevant commit using `createCommit` function.

Answer (score 1):

On the Git side, `git status` runs two diffs:

- The first diff compares the `HEAD` commit to Git's index.  Whatever is different here is `staged for commit` (or the first character in `git status --short`).
- The second diff compares Git's index vs the working tree.  Whatever is different here is `not staged for commit` (or the second character in `git status --short`).

Although you just ran `git status`, the output looks like that from `git status --short` (did you `git config status.short true`?).  The <kbd>SPACE</kbd>`D` here would mean that the file exists in Git's index, but not in the working tree.

I'll have to leave the Haskell side to someone else.